# Java regex to split words in a sentences with value and its metric as single word

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to split a sentence into a set of words. What I am looking is to consider also the metric when chunking numbers.

```
E.g (Made-up).
 document= The root cause of the problem is the temperature, it is currently 40 degrees which is 30 percent likely to turn into an infection doctor has prescribed 1-19666 tablet which contains 1.67 gpm and has advised to consume them every 3 hrs.
```

What is required, are set of words

```
the
root
cause
problem
...
40 degrees
30 percent
1.67 gpm
1-19666 tablet
3 hrs
```

What I have tried is

```
List<String> bagOfWords = new ArrayList<>();    
String [] words = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(document.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z_.-]", " ")).split(" ");
for(String word :words){
    bagOfWords.add(StringUtils.normalizeSpace(word.replaceAll("\\.(?!\\d)", " ")));         
    }                
System.out.println("NEW 2 :: " + bagOfWords.toString());
```

Comment: are you looking for a Regex that can solve this or looking for something that could work for any sentence?

Comment: for any sentence. basically to pull out the value with its units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's **assume** that one word that contains a number is followed by another one that doesn't. Then here is the code:

```
    private static final String DOC = "The root cause of the problem is the temperature, it is currently 40 degrees which is 30 percent likely to turn into an infection doctor has prescribed 1-19666 tablet which contains 1.67 gpm and has advised to consume them every 3 hrs";

   // ...

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\b\\S*\\d\\S*\\b\\s+)?\\b\\S+\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(DOC);
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        words.add(matcher.group());
    }
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

Explanation:

- `\\b` finds word boundary
- `\\S` is a non-space character. So you can have everything within a word, like dot or comma.
- `(...)?` is the first optional part. It catches the word with a number, if any. I.e. it has some characters (`\\S*`), then a number (`\\d`), then again, some characters (`\\S*`)
- The second word is simple: at least one non-whitespace character. Hence it has a `+`, not a `*` after the `S`.

Answer (score 1):

You question scope is a bit large, but here's a hack that can work for most sentences in this format.

First you can create a list of prefixes, which contains keywords of you units like `hrs, tablet, gpm ...` once you have this what you need becomes easy to pick out.

```
    String document= "The root cause of the problem is the temperature, it is currently 40 degrees which is 30 percent likely to turn into an infection doctor has prescribed 1-19666 tablet which contains 1.67 gpm and has advised to consume them every 3 hrs.";
    if(document.endsWith(".")){
        document = document.substring(0, document.length() -1 );
    }
    System.out.println(document);
    String[] splitted = document.split(" ");
    List<String> keywords = new ArrayList();
    keywords.add("degrees");
    keywords.add("percent");
    keywords.add("gpm");
    keywords.add("tablet");
    keywords.add("hrs");

    List<String> words = new ArrayList();

    for(String s : splitted){
        if(!s.equals(",")){
            //if s is not a comma;
            if(keywords.contains(s) && words.size()!=0){
                //if s is a keyword append to last item in list
                int lastIndex = words.size()-1;
                words.set(lastIndex, words.get(lastIndex)+" "+s);
            }
            else{
                words.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    for(String s : words){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```